# Trying to figure out a way to find consecutive elements in a list

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is: for every instance of two consecutive vowels in a list, the second one will become accented, but only if the previous one is unaccented. Still new to Python, this is what I have now:

```
sample = ['b' 'e', 'a', 'a', 'e'] 
vowels = "ae"

def accenting(list):
    vowel_changes = {
        "a": "á",
        "e": "é",
    }
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        if list[i] in vowels and list[i + 1] in vowels:
            vowel_to_change = list[i + 1]
            for replacement in vowel_changes:
                if replacement in vowel_to_change:
                    vowel_to_change = vowel_to_change.replace(replacement, vowel_changes[replacement])
            print(vowel_to_change)
    return list

print(accenting(sample))
```

The goal is to have something like: ['b' 'e', 'á', 'a', 'é']. Right now it returns 'á', 'á', and 'é'. So the two things I'm having trouble figuring out are 1) putting the replacement back into its respective spot in the list, and 2) having the function change every other vowel instead of each one. I think I might need to cut up and create a new list for 1, and maybe have another condition for 2? Not sure.

Comment: 1) You just need to assign to that index in the list. What's so hard about that? 2) Fixing point 1 will fix this. However, the code you've posted raises an IndexError for `list[i + 1]`. You can [edit] the question to fix it. See [mre] and [ask] for advice.

Comment: Also you're missing a comma in `sample`.

Comment: BTW `list` is a bad variable name since it shadows the builtin.

Answer (score 0):

Lookahead can be messy, especially with edge conditions. What if list is zero or the last element isn't a vowel and `list[i + 1]` goes off the end of the list? Another option is to track state as you go.

```
sample = ['b', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'e'] 

def accenting(sample_list):
    vowel_changes = {
        "a": "á",
        "e": "é",
    }
    was_unaccented_vowel = False
    for i, c  in enumerate(sample_list):
        if c in vowel_changes:
            if was_unaccented_vowel:
                sample_list[i] = vowel_changes[c]
                was_unaccented_vowel = False
            else:
                was_unaccented_vowel = True
        else:
            was_unaccented_vowel = False
    return sample_list 

print(accenting(sample))
```

That code changed the original sample list. You could turn it into a generator with the `yield` statement and make a new copy

```
sample = ['b', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'e'] 

def accenting(sample_list):
    vowel_changes = {
        "a": "á",
        "e": "é",
    }
    was_unaccented_vowel = False
    for c in sample_list:
        if c in vowel_changes:
            if was_unaccented_vowel:
                c = vowel_changes[c]
                was_unaccented_vowel = False
            else:
                was_unaccented_vowel = True
        else:
            was_unaccented_vowel = False
        yield c

print(list(accenting(sample)))
```

I also fiddled around with a state machine although I'd be hard pressed to claim its better

```
sample = ['b', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'e'] 

vowel_changes = {
    "a": "á",
    "e": "é",
}

def _state_no_accent_check(c):
    if c in vowel_changes:
        return _state_accent_check, c
    else:
        return _state_no_accent_check, c

def _state_accent_check(c):
    return _state_no_accent_check, vowel_changes.get(c, c)

def accenting(sample_list):
    state = _state_no_accent_check
    for c in sample_list:
        state, c = state(c)
        yield c

print(list(accenting(sample)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with this code:

The first and most important is that it raises an IndexError (at least in Python3.7 which I used) because on line 10 you try to access list[i+1] while you are at the end of the list, so you fall off the end of the list and raise and Exception. In other words, it tries to access list[5] when the highest index in the list is 4, and so it doesn't know what to do and crashes. I would suggest fixing this by looking backward instead of forward. By that I mean: instead of checking whether list[i+1] is a vowel, check whether list[i-1] is a vowel. That way, you can start from index 1 since index 0 can't be a consecutive vowel anyway. Keep in mind that you'll have to pay attention not to accent the third vowel in a row; I'll let you think about how to fix that.

The second is that you're way overthinking how to replace the letter in the list. You can simply say `list[i] = vowel_changes[replacement]`

Answer (score 0):

There's a few changes here that we can make to both make it do what you want and to remove extra lines of code that aren't actually needed.

```
def accenting(lst): # Use lst instead of list. list is a python reserved keyword.
```

First change the loop so we don't go out of range on it list.
Since we are looking ahead, we want to stop one before the length of the list so we can look at the next one

```
for i in range(0, len(list)-1):
```

We need to change the condition for checking lst[i+1]. You had it checking if lst[i+1] was in vowels. But that doesn't mean it's a consecutive. It could be the case of ae next to each other. You already check lst[i] is in vowels, so we can just check if lst[i+1] is equal to that.

Then the if statement can be expanded with another and to cover the condition of not giving the accent to multiples.

In the parenthesis we check that i is not equal to 0 so that the whole parenthesis will not count for the first letter in the array, because there are no letters before it. Then we check if the letter before is equal to the current letter.

```
if lst[i] in vowels and lst[i+1] == lst[i] and (i != 0 and lst[i-1] != lst[i]):
```

Inside of the if statement we can get rid of all the variables and the second loop. Since we know the location in lst we can directly assign it. We also know the key we want the value for in vowels, so there is no need for the loop.

```
lst[i] = vowels[lst[i]]]
```

After that you can just return the list.

The total code looks like this.

```
sample = ['b' 'e', 'a', 'a', 'e'] 
vowels = "ae"

def accenting(lst):
    vowel_changes = {
        "a": "á",
        "e": "é",
    }
    for i in range(0, len(list)-1):
        if lst[i] in vowels and lst[i+1] == lst[i] and (i != 0 and lst[i-1] != lst[i]):
            lst[i] = vowels[lst[i]]]

    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to represent the required letter mapping and zip to pair each character with its predecessor.  Using a list comprehension you can get the result in one line:

```
mapping  = { ("e","e"):"é", ("a","a"):"á" }

sample   = ['b','e', 'a', 'a', 'e','c','e','e','z'] 
accented = [ {(a,b):b,**mapping}[(a,b)] for a,b in zip([""]+sample,sample) ]

print(accented)
# ['b', 'e', 'a', 'á', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'é', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation that mutates the list.

```
sample = ['b', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'e']
vowel_changes = {"a": "á", "e": "é"}

# Start from index 1 and use items (i-1, i) to avoid an IndexError
for i in range(1, len(sample)):
    c, d = sample[i-1], sample[i]
    # Check if the two items are both unaccented vowels
    if all(x in vowel_changes for x in [c, d]):
        # Accent the second vowel
        sample[i] = vowel_changes[d]

print(sample)  # -> ['b', 'e', 'á', 'a', 'é']
```

If you wanted to put this in a function, you could use `list.copy()` to avoid mutating the input.